# FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am developing an asp.net mvc application and have created my custom user database and registration procedure (need email verification). Can I use FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie with my own login procedure, without dealing with asp.net's membership provider? Will doing so work with the [Authorize] attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie` within your own login procedure, in fact, that's what the default asp.net mvc template uses.

`[Authorize]` will work since FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie populates `HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` to true.

Comment: Hi Alex, FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie should populate HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated to true but on some of our machine it doesn't. Do you have any idea what can I look for to debug this. It is being really annoying!